# Counting consecutive rows that meet a specific conditon in time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe that looks like the screenshot below (Data is reproducible below). I need to count the number of consecutive rows above 0.1 until the last row. In other words, starting from row 18 and going backwards, a count of the consecutive rows above 0.1.
The results for each column should be:

```
48184 = 18
57256 = 8
63893 = 0
```

I have attempted placing a mask on the dataframe but I don't know how to ensure that the mask only accounts for consecutive rows beginning from row 18 backwards. Any help is much appreciated!

```
    48184       57256       63893
0   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
1   0.291498    0.004463    0.015055
2   0.430303    0.004463    0.015055
3   0.430303    0.004463    0.021197
4   0.430303    0.004463    0.006142
5   0.430303    0.029888    0.029561
6   0.430303    0.048527    0.029561
7   0.430303    0.073234    0.023419
8   0.430303    0.047989    0.041190
9   0.430303    0.077472    0.017771
10  0.430303    0.085486    0.017771
11  0.430303    0.117013    0.017771
12  0.430303    0.159811    0.057744
13  0.430303    0.182291    0.108666
14  0.430303    0.152748    0.068693
15  0.430303    0.140596    0.033474
16  0.430303    0.210749    0.097302
17  0.430303    0.201838    0.097302
18  0.430303    0.249361    0.097302
```

Comment: Keep the other format. Text data is better looking than pictures.

Comment: Can't seem to roll it back. How do I get the text data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `idxmax` on `df<=0.1`:

```
s = df.le(0.1)
len(s) - 1 - s.loc[::-1].idxmax()
```

Output:

```
48184    18
57256     8
63893     0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: When I run this, I am getting 19, 9 and 1

Comment: A, that's because `len(s)=19`. You may want to subtract them all by 1 :-)

Comment: Ok grand. Thanks!